# Make categories on my qualitative variable column

Tags: python, categorical-data, lexical-analysis

I need to categorise my qualitative variables into groups:
For example: on one of my qualitative columns ("packaging"),
I have to group all my plastic data like "Plastic", "film-plastic", fr-film_plastic in a category "plastics".

I have to make several categories, like Plastic, cardboard, metal.

I used `str.extract`, to solve this problem, but I have a problem with multidimensional key.

```
plastique = data.loc[data['packaging_tags'].str.contains("plas", regex= True, na=False)]
>>> print(plastique['packaging_tags'].unique().tolist())
'teabag-in-plastic-in-cardboard-box', 'plastic-pouch', 'plastica', 'clamshell,plastic,fresh', 'plastic,hdpe', 'bolsa,plastico', 'en-mixed-plastic-bag,en-pet-lid', 'carton,metal,plastic,tray,en-card-box,en-pet-tray', 'en-mixed-plastic-sleeve', 'empaque-de-plastico', 'en-mixed-plastic-packet,en-pet-tray', 'sacchetto-di-plastica', 'carton,glass,plastic', 'en-card-box,en-mixed-plastic-film', 'en-card-box,en-mixed-plastic-wrapper', 'en-glass-jar,en-other-plastic-cap', 'en-mixed-plastic-unknown'
```

On using `str.extract` or `str.contains`, I get a `ValueError`:

```
plastique = data.loc[data['packaging_tags'].str.extract("([^,']{0,15}plas[^,']{1,30})")]
>>> print(plastique['packaging_tags'].unique().tolist()) 
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

I would then like to make a dictionary of the groups to use:

```
dict_col = {'Carton': data.loc[data['packaging_tags'].str.extract("([^,]{0,15}car[^,]{1,30})")],
            'Plastique':data.loc[data['packaging_tags'].str.extract("([^, ]{0,15}plas[^,]{1,30})"]}

d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in dict_col.items() for k in oldv}

data['packaging_tags'] = data['packaging_tags'].map(d)
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of `data`? For example, `data.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: Yeep   'code': {0: '00000000000000225',
  1: '00000000000003429145',
  2: '0000000000017',
  3: '0000000000031',
  4: '000000000003327986'},
 'creator': {0: 'nutrinet-sante',
  1: 'kiliweb',
  2: 'kiliweb',
  3: 'isagoofy',
  4: 'kiliweb'},,
 'product_name': {0: 'jeunes pousses',
  1: 'L.casei',
  2: 'Vitória crackers',
  3: 'Cacao',
  4: 'Filetes de pollo empanado'},
 'packaging_tags': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'countries': {0: 'en:france',
  1: 'Spain',
  2: 'France',
  3: 'France',
  4: 'Espagne'},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
import numpy as np

cond = [
    df['packaging_tags'].str.contains(('^plas$'), case=False, regex=True),
    df['packaging_tags'].str.contains(('^met$'), case=False, regex=True),
    df['packaging_tags'].str.contains(('^card$'), case=False, regex=True)
]

choice = ['PLASTIC', 'METAL', 'CARDBOARD']

data['cat_var'] = np.select(cond, choice)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not think about the select variable.

I changed back my numpy variable to a panda variable and it was good :)